# Magento 2 : Import product error

Tags: magento2, csv, import-products

I have a product csv file and when I import it in admin then is the result https://prnt.sc/pf3rhl Thank in advance.

update:
I did change all ” to " and this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Change your quotes as mentioned in the error

Comment: I tried, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details, what line gives the error & what did you try,etc

Comment: please check my update.